# Why is scanning my network picking up the wrong Interface, mac, and ip address?

Tags: networking, windows-10, ethernet, vmware, network-interface

So I've just used an application to scan for pc's on my network as a shortcut for wake on lan.  Two of the three pc's show up with spot on information in its entirety.  The one illustrated in the photo, has everything incorrect barring the host name.

I have went into device manager and disabled the vm adapter, which then passes to the other vm adapter.   only upon disabling them both does it actually pick up the proper interface & associated information.  This is obviously not a solution and I'd like to understand why its happening and how to fix it.

I have done a Get-NetIPInterface and the metric is higher than my ethernet adapter.   I've inflated it further just to be safe, with no change so evidently that is not the root of the issue.  If someone could advise id be appreciative.  As you can see in the app, you can specify the ip range to scan, and the ip it's picking up for the problem pc isn't even IN the range.  The IP it should be picking up is 192.168.1.1 so it evidently see's it on some level.

The application is aquilatech Wake On LAN https://github.com/basildane/WakeOnLAN

[image]

EDIT - I received some information pointing to it being a problem with the codebase as best i can understand it.

> So... Looking through the code, I think function GetWmIdata
>   (GetWMIdata) in Search.vb has a logic defect (if I am understanding
>   the code correctly – I last used Visual Basic about 20 years ago, and
>   last used CIM/WMI many years ago, so take my analysis with a large
>   pinch of salt). Upon connecting to a remote host, it fetches the
>   computer name and OS name, then loops through every IP-enabled NIC on
>   the host. For each NIC in the host, it:
>
> Picks the last IP address assigned to the NIC and uses that as
>   "ipaddress";
>
> Extracts` the description from the NIC and uses that as
>   "netinterface";
>
> Extracts the MAC address from the NIC and uses that as "macaddress";
>
> Checks the NIC for power-management capabilities, wake capabilities
>   and WoL capabilities. When multiple NICs are present, it appears to
>   continue looping away until it has enumerated them all, but in each
>   case it overwrites any previously-discovered properties with those of
>   the latest-discovered NIC (except for the power-management and wake
>   capabilities... those end up set to true if any NIC has those
>   capabilities). I do not see any code there which actually verifies
>   that it is choosing the properties from the NIC which is connected to
>   the interface over which it is performing the probe... or even that
>   the interface is reachable from the network from which the probe is
>   being performed. It simply walks the list of NICs in the system and
>   ends up using the properties from the last NIC it finds, whichever
>   that happens to be.
>
> I think function GetWMIdata needs to evaluate the reachability of that
>   interface from the scan host, and take that into consideration when
>   choosing which NIC's properties to return.
>
> Hope this is of some use (and is not completely misleading or
>   wrong...).

Comment: What application is this, yes, it does matter.

Comment: I will edit the main post to include said information, its aquilatech's Wake On LAN.  https://github.com/basildane/WakeOnLAN